# Is is possible to join 2 tables if one of them has duplicate values in the column that's joining?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

let's say I'm Joining the `Shoes` table to the `Clothes` table,  They both have a column called `ShoesID`, so to me it would make sense to join those 2 tables on `ShoesID` (it also happens to be the primary key of the `Shoes` table). But here's my problem, it's not the primary key of the `Clothes` table, so in the `Clothes` table, in the `ShoesID` column, some of the rows repeat themselves and that's ruining my join.

Is there a way to get around that?

```
Clothes Table
ClothesID   ShoesID   NakedVarchar
99      |1           |  e|
100     |1           |  f|
101     |4           |  g|
102     |4           |  d|

I want to join this to this:



Shoes Table

ShoesID  Descriptionvarchar
|1        |  a|
|2        |  b|
|3        |  c|
|4        |  d|
```

so I figured the logical way of doing this would be to do

`LEFT JOIN Clothes ON Shoes.ShoesID = Clothes.ShoesID`

unfortunately because the Clothes table contains duplicates it seems Postgres cuts them out,
I'd like all the data to be joined including the duplicates, how can I get around this?

it's not as simple as reversing my join statement as I'm technically trying to join them in a big
query that has got many other joins.

Comment: What criteria do you use to determine which row of the Clothes table to associate to a given row of the Shoes table besides the `ShoesID`?

Comment: Not sure if Postgre supports it or not (I expect it does) but in say SQL Server you could join a subquery that eliminates the dupes.

Comment: Well, Postgres does eliminate the dupes, that's partially my issue, I'd like the tables to be joined properly and include the dupes within the join and I have to use the ShoesID as the criteria from the looks of it.

Comment: @JNK So does MySQL and from what I recall so does PostgreSQL.

Comment: @user519753 Why is that an issue?  If you have multiple entries in `Clothes` table with the same `ShoeID` join should return you duplicate rows.  You can introduce other criteria if you have it to get single row back.

Comment: Are you saying that each row in Shoes should only be matched to a single row in Clothes ?

Comment: Perhaps you should include some sample data, your SQL, the results you're seeing, and the results you're expecting.

Comment: Well what's going on is that in this example ShoesID is what I'm using to join `ON` so I need the duplicates to be included because the data (aside from ShoesID) in the tables that I'm joining is unique.

Answer (score 1):

you can make any join that you want to, even a "self-join", but if there is no coincidence or match between the keywords your query could be empty.  if you want to list them all, you should use a UNION instead of a join.